# Movie about a space ship with a precious cargo

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

All I remember is that everyone in the space ship was asleep except one person. I think he was the security officer on board. They had to travel for 3 years but the flight got interrupted by bandits that boarded the ship. A big chunk of the movie was about the lonely security guy, he was running around in his PJ-s and dancing to classical music and stuff. I think the movie is made in the 90s.

Comment: Closest match I've found so far is Disney's *RocketMan* released in 1997, but that's a computer tech traveling to Mars, it's a period only of months, and the interruption was due to technical difficulties. Doubt that's what you're looking for, but it's an answer to rule out.

Comment: Thanks for looking, but yes its not the one. Oh and I think the ship was carrying GOLD.

Answer (score 3):

Your description and particularly the lonesome security officer horsing around in his underwear matches *Velocity Trap* ([IMDb article](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120435/), [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_Trap)).
He is portrayed by martial artist Olivier Gruner.

[image]

2 minor discrepancies: the ship is carrying 40 billions(!) of universal dollars in cash, not gold, and the trip is for a couple of months, not 3 years.

Comment: LOL - Apparently someone did watch this movie and did strongly dislike it? Both the question *and* my answer received a downvote sometime during the last hour...